# A Simple Inquality with Expected Value

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Given $X(k) \ge -1, \;\;k=1,2,3...,N$  be discrete random variable with distribution $f_X$ and assume $a \in [0,1]$ so that $aX(k) \ge -1$ for all $k$ and
>   $$
> 1 - E \left[ \prod_{i=1}^N(1+aX(i)) \right] \leq \varepsilon. \;\;\;\; (*)
> $$where $\varepsilon \in [0,1]$.

Then by using $X(k) \ge -1$ and $(*)$, I can conclude
$$
1 - E \left[ \prod_{i=1}^N(1+aX(i)) \right] \leq 1 - \prod_{i=1}^N(1 + a \cdot (-1))
$$

But I was wondering can I conclude further that the Right-Hand-Side also less than $\varepsilon$? I mean
$$
1 - \prod_{i=1}^N(1 + a \cdot (-1)) \leq \varepsilon?
$$

I think I can since that $a$ I chosen must make $(*)$ hold for all $X \ge -1$, but not sure.

Thank you.

Comment: Is $k$ an index, or an element of the sample space?

Comment: I treat $k$ as index

Comment: OK, I'd re-write your equations with $k$ as a subscript then. Random variables are functions, so its a little confusing.